# It is possible to stream full length audio tracks from Deezer using the api from C++ application?

Tags: c++, deezer

I would like to extend an open source music player for desktop written in C++/Qt by adding Deezer audio stream support. It is possible to stream the full length audio from Deezer after ensuring that the user is logged in with a Premium+ account?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which player? :-)

Comment: @Peque https://www.clementine-player.org/ it already has support for Spotify and Soundclound audio streaming

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no C++ service available on Deezer. Please refer to the developers documentation to see which SDK are available (http://developers.deezer.com/)

Comment: @Angéline I don't need a SDK for this, I just want to know if it is possible to get the URL to the full audio track

Answer (score 1):

Getting the URL of the full audio track is not possible unless you interact with the player.